# Can an octagon be plotted when given only it's inner radius?

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to programmatically plot an octagon, and I can do this pretty simply when given the size of a face on the octagon. The "clip" distance, or distance between two subsequent non-parallel points in one dimension is `faceSize/sqrt(2)`. I want to draw an octagon by being given only the inner radius (or the face size plus each clipped side).

So, given `innerRadius = faceSize/2 + (faceSize / sqrt(2))`, can `faceSize` be deduced when only `innerRadius` is provided? Or is there another route I should go down to find these points? I know how to plot it when given the inner and out radii.

I've been using Objective-C's UIBezierPath to draw the octagon's path

```
CGFloat faceSize = 25;
CGFloat clipSize = faceSize / sqrt(2);
CGFloat clipAndFaceSize = clipSize + faceSize;
CGFloat fullSize = faceSize + clipSize*2;

CGFloat offset = (faceSize/2 + clipSize) * -1; // will make the center of the octagon 0,0
faceSize += offset;
clipSize += offset;
clipAndFaceSize += offset;
fullSize += offset;

UIBezierPath *octagon = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
[octagon moveToPoint:   CGPointMake(clipSize,        offset)];          // start
[octagon addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(clipAndFaceSize, offset)];          // bottom face
[octagon addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(fullSize,        clipSize)];        // bot right face
[octagon addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(fullSize,        clipAndFaceSize)]; // right face
[octagon addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(clipAndFaceSize, fullSize)];        // top right face
[octagon addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(clipSize,        fullSize)];        // top face
[octagon addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(offset,          clipAndFaceSize)]; // top left face
[octagon addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(offset,          clipSize)];        // left face
[octagon addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(clipSize,        offset)];          // bot left face
```

Comment: Going by $r=f/2+f/\sqrt2$ you can solve for $f$. $$f=\frac{2\sqrt2\ r}{2+\sqrt2}$$

Comment: this gave me `2f`, not `f`, but it still works when that's considered. If you move this into an answer I can accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let innerRadius be $r$ and faceSize be $f$.

You have

$$r = \frac{f}{2}+\frac{f}{\sqrt2}$$
$$2\sqrt2\ r = \sqrt2\ f+2f$$
$$2\sqrt2\ r = f(\sqrt2+2)$$
$$\frac{2\sqrt2\ r}{\sqrt2+2} = f$$